# Does Kafka guarantee zero message loss?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm reading contradictory views on this. I have a critical application and every message is important. So does kafka guarantees zero message loss at same level of other traditional messaging systems like IBM MQ?

Comment: "zero message loss" is pretty wide and vague. Can you clarify what you mean? Is it delivery end to end? Is it durability once in the system? At least Once or Exactly Once semantics?

Comment: Here I mean delivery end to end. Does Kafka guarantee it? My understanding is that it should be. But I'm reading here and it there that it doesn't and that it's suitable for situations where few messages loss isn't a big deal, like logging, sensor data...etc

Answer (score 2):

Every *topic*, is a particular stream of data (similar to a table in a database). Topics, are split into *partitions* (as many as you like) where each message within a partition gets an incremental id, known as offset as shown below.

**Partition 0:**

```
+---+---+---+-----+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | ... |
+---+---+---+-----+
```

**Partition 1:**

```
+---+---+---+---+----+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | .. |
+---+---+---+---+----+
```

Now a Kafka cluster is composed of multiple *brokers*. Each broker is identified with an ID and can contain certain topic partitions.

Example of 2 topics (each having 3 and 2 partitions respectively):

**Broker 1:**

```
+-------------------+
|      Topic 1      |
|    Partition 0    |
|                   |
|                   |
|     Topic 2       |
|   Partition 1     |
+-------------------+
```

**Broker 2:**

```
+-------------------+
|      Topic 1      |
|    Partition 2    |
|                   |
|                   |
|     Topic 2       |
|   Partition 0     |
+-------------------+
```

**Broker 3:**

```
+-------------------+
|      Topic 1      |
|    Partition 1    |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
+-------------------+
```

Note that data is distributed (and *Broker 3* doesn't hold any data of *topic 2*).

Topics, should have a `replication-factor` > 1 (usually 2 or 3) so that when a broker is down, another one can serve the data of a topic. For instance, assume that we have a topic with 2 partitions with a `replication-factor` set to 3 as shown below:

**Broker 1:**

```
+-------------------+
|      Topic 1      |
|    Partition 0    |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
+-------------------+
```

**Broker 2:**

```
+-------------------+
|      Topic 1      |
|    Partition 0    |
|                   |
|                   |
|     Topic 1       |
|   Partition 0     |
+-------------------+
```

**Broker 3:**

```
+-------------------+
|      Topic 1      |
|    Partition 1    |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
+-------------------+
```

Now assume that *Broker 2* has failed. *Broker 1* and 3 can still serve the data for topic 1. So a `replication-factor` of 3 is always a good idea since it allows for one broker to be taken down for maintenance purposes and also for another one to be taken down unexpectedly. ***Therefore, Apache-Kafka offers strong durability and fault tolerance guarantees.***

**Note about Leaders:**
At any time, only one broker can be a leader of a partition and only that leader can receive and serve data for that partition. The remaining brokers will just synchronize the data (in-sync replicas). Also note that when the `replication-factor` is set to 1, the *leader* cannot be moved elsewhere when a broker fails. In general, when all replicas of a partition fail or go offline, the `leader` will automatically be set to `-1`.